# Can "diff" be forced to sync at a specified point?

Tags: linux, cygwin, diff

I am merging source files that include different versions of the same functions.  The functions are not necessarily in the same order in the different files.  For example, `foo.c` might contain `baz()` followed by `quux()`, while `bar.c` contains `quux()` followed by `baz()`.

I would like to force `diff` to sync up at the first line of the function I'm currently working on so that I can see just the changes in that function.  Is there a way to do that with GNU `diff` (or another diff utility)?  I have three workarounds, none of which is great:

1. Copy the functions to separate files and `diff` those files.  Slow and cumbersome, plus risks copy-and-paste error.
2. Move the function of interest up to the top of each file, then diff the files.  A bit easier, but still time-consuming.
3. Add a chunk of lorem ipsum text before each file.  (This is the one I am currently using.)  Doesn't require moving code around, but hey - why should I have to do work the machine is perfectly capable of doing? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gnu diff won't do it unfortunately, and trying to use `split` in front of it will not be practical at all.

Some comparison tools will let you match lines forcefully with so called "synchronization links", Araxis will do it (using Wine on Linux), Beyond Compare as well for example.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like ExamDiff Pro will add well... now to decide which to pony up for :)